# How to "assemble" a python variable name using another variable?

Tags: python-3.x

From a given library, I would read data like:

```
data = msg.chan6_raw
```

The msg looks like:

```
RC_CHANNELS {
  time_boot_ms : 1730680, 
  chancount : 16, 
  chan1_raw : 1500, 
  chan2_raw : 1500, 
  chan3_raw : 1000, 
  chan4_raw : 1500, 
  chan5_raw : 1800, 
  chan6_raw : 1000, 
  chan7_raw : 1000, 
  chan8_raw : 1800, 
  chan9_raw : 0, 
  chan10_raw : 0, 
  chan11_raw : 0, 
  chan12_raw : 0, 
  chan13_raw : 0, 
  chan14_raw : 0, 
  chan15_raw : 0, 
  chan16_raw : 0, 
  chan17_raw : 0, 
  chan18_raw : 0, 
  rssi : 0
}
```

My code knows that I would like to read channel "6" which is in a variable named "number".

I can't do:

```
data = 'msg.chan' + str(number) + '_raw'
```

But that is the desired result.

So the question is: how can I "assemble" this request, based on "number"  - to fetch the correct data?

Comment: if `msg` is a dictionary you can access it by keywords like this `data = msg['chan' + str(number) + '_raw']`

Comment: For what it's worth, accessing via braces is generally bad practice, because if the specified key isn't there it'll blow up your code. Instead, you want to use `get` and specify an appropriate default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `RC_CHANNELS` object is in the form of a dictionary. If this is the case you should be able to do this:

```
RC_CHANNELS.get(f"chan{number}_raw")
```

If not then you probably want to first put your message into that form, making this trivial. Feel free to update your question with information about the type of your `msg` if you need help with this.

So you understand what's going on:

- `dict` support a `get` operation, which will get the value for a given key. Keys are often, though not always, `str`s, so you infer the name of the key you're looking for.
- An 'f-string' is a string like this: `f"Some string with a {value}"`. In this case it will auto-format your string, splicing in whatever the string-representation of the variable `value`. Thus, if `value = 1` it would result in `"Some string with a 1"`. This is equivalent to `"Some string with a {value}".format(value = value)`.

Comment: I tried to test what "msg" is by "type(msg)" but get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
This is the pymavlink library
Your method works if I do msg.to_dict() first, but it would be nice not to have to. (in case it's CPU intensive)

Comment: You will have to parse your message at some point; if it is providing a `to_dict` method that is probably the best way to do it, and it's probably not that CPU intensive unless it is much much larger than the sample you provided. I would not worry about that unless you end up in a situation in which things are running very slowly - and then I'd profile it from there rather than guessing.